# Creating expire date with mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a user registration system with mysql and php and added a column to user table called 'date_expires' ( with DATE NOT NULL) to make registered users' registration date to expire. With my form users can select their registration period. Eg: 1 year, 2 year, 3 year. etc. I have got the value of registration period when user submitting the form.. like this

```
$registrationPeriod = $_POST['registration_period];
```

My problem is how I insert expire date with above value to my user table?

I am trying to insert data to the user table but confusing how I do it with 'date_expires' column.

This is my code so far...

```
$q = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, pass, first_name, last_name, date_expires) 
      VALUES ('$u', '$e', '$p, '$fn', '$ln', ????????????? )";
```

hope someone help me out about this..
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `$_POST['registration_period']` comes in as `1 year, 2 year`... Then you can most easily strip off the integer value and perform the date calcualtion in MySQL like `NOW() + INTERVAL n YEAR` where `n` is the number.

```
// Extract it from the registration_period
// Since it is formatted as "n years" with a space between,
// we can split the string on the space.  list() assigns an array (returned from explode())
// to individual variables. Since we only actually need one of them (the number), 
// we can throw away the second (which is the string "years") by just giving list() one variable
// It still needs a placeholder for the second though, hence the extra comma.
list($years,) = explode(" ", $_POST['registration_period']);
// Make sure it is an int to protect against SQL injection...
$years = intval($years);
```

In your query, substitute the number into the date calculation in the `VALUES ()` list:

```
INSERT INTO users (.......) VALUES (....., (NOW() + INTERVAL $years YEAR));
```

Please consider switching to an API which supports prepared statements, like MySQLi or PDO. We can only hope and assume that all your query input variables have been correctly sanitized and filtered against SQL injection in your query's current form.

```
$u = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['u']);
$e = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['e']);
// etc for all query vars...
```

([More info on `list()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

Comment: thank for your answer.. please can you explain this line little.. list($years,) = explode(" ", $_POST['registration_period']);

Comment: 1 year, 2 year, 3 year or just 1 , 2 , 3 ect.. from php

Comment: @TharangaNuwan Then use `list()` exactly as I have it above.

Comment: `substr($_POST['registration_period'], 0, strpos($_POST['registration_period'], ' '));` should also work in extracting the year if the string is `1 year` etc.

Comment: is it not a problem using 'year' or 'years'?

Comment: DATE_ADD() function actually need?

Comment: @TharangaNuwan In the PHP? No it does not matter, because both `list()` and the `substr()` method h2ooooooo mentioned will throw away the `year/years` string since it isn't needed by MySQL at all.  It could be `3 anything` and still work.

Comment: @TharangaNuwan `DATE_ADD()` is not actually needed in newer MySQL versions. You can manipulate dates just with `date_column + INTERVAL n <interval_name>`.

Comment: Try it out in your MySQL client (phpmyadmin or whatever) `SELECT NOW() + INTERVAL 1 YEAR`  will be `2014-01-21 09:03:00` ...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it two ways.

### PHP

Using [`strtotime("+2 years")`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php):

```
$expireYears = 2;
$expireDate = strtotime("+" . $expireYears . " years");
```

---

### MySQL

Using [`DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 YEAR)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
$expireYears = 2;
$q = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, pass, first_name, last_name, date_expires) 
      VALUES ('$u', '$e', '$p, '$fn', '$ln', DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL $expireYears YEAR))";
```